# Project Not deploy on emulator in xamarin android native app

Tags: xamarin

Console Output Message:

> Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this
>   project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go into emulator "Settings >Apps> All" and delete your application.
[image]

Comment: Hi.. I am not able to find this setting can you send me screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates you are not deploying the created binary to the device.

In Visual Studio open the dropdown that says "Debug", select "Configuration Manager" and make sure the checkbox "Deploy" is set for your Android project for the configuration you use.